# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_GoogleAnalytics magento

Tags: magento

In my magento shop I see the following error after installing magento 1.9:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Helper_Data::getAccountId() in /var/www/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/googleanalytics/ga.phtml on line 29

When I disable Mage_GoogleAnalytics in my settings the error disappeared and my site is working again.

Could anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Added block for the error message.

Answer (score 1):

When you upgrade magento then all core files not update sometimes then this issue come.

You need to make sure all files for GoogleAnalytics available and updated. You can check here:

1. /app/code/core/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/
2. /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/googleanalytics.xml
3. /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/googleanalytics/ga.phtml

You can compare these files from new installation and update if need.

After that clear cache.

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to tweak your settings and flush cache.

Open magento admin panel and under system->configuration ensure you have your google analytics account entered. If you have multiple website/store scopes visit each one to be sure.

Make sure to flush all caches afterwards.

Comment: I just checked al my three sites. They al have the right account number in the google-API settings. I flushes my cashe many times but the error is still showing. Also when I try one of my sites to enable the google analytics setting this only one site is giving the error. The other two are still working without error...but the analitics is disabled.

thanx

Comment: Please post the contents of your app/design/frontend/base/default/template/googleanalytics/ga.phtml

Comment: I already found it:
I replaced <reference name="head" before="-"> with the following: <reference name="after_body_start">